# How many turns are needed to get a length L of the steel blade roll?

Tags: mathematical-physics

I'm doing a college project and I came across the need to calculate how many turns it takes to get a length $L$ of a steel blade roll. I am not able to develop a formula for this.
The roll length formula I'm using is:$$L=\frac{\pi}{T}\cdot \left (\left (\frac{d_2}{2}\right )^2-\left (\frac{d_1}{2}\right )^2\right ).$$And here is a sketch of the roll:

> [image]

Comment: Your question should state what $T$ is. People may guess it is the thickness but you should state it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is equivalent to
$$
L \cdot T = \pi\, {r_2}^2 - \pi\, {r_1}^2, 
\tag{$\dagger$}
\label{length}
$$
where $L$ is the length, $T$ is the thickness, and $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the inner and outer radii, respectively. This is clearly a correct approximation, as each is a description of the area of the cross-section region: an annulus, which is a circle with a smaller circle removed.

Imagine that the annulus is filled in with concentric thickened circles (rather than the actual more subtle shape: a thickened spiral). The innermost circle has radius $r_1$, then next circle has radius $r_1 + T$ the next $r_1 + 2T$, etc. The outermost circle has radius $r_2 = r_1 + n T$, where
$$
n = \frac{r_2 - r_1}{T}. 
$$
Again, we're approximating things by assuming that $T$ is very small compared to the radii, so $n$ is quite large and be assumed to be an integer.

Now the total length is the sum of the circumferences of the circles:
\begin{align}
L &= 2\pi r_1 + 2\pi (r_1 + T) + 2\pi (r_1 + 2T) 
+ \cdots + 2\pi (r_1 + nT) \\
&= 2\pi \biggl( (n+1) r_1 + (0 + 1 + 2 + \cdots + n)T \biggr), 
\end{align}
and using the well-known formula for the triangle number
$$
1 + 2 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}, 
$$
we have
$$
L = 2\pi(n+1)\, r_1 + \pi n(n+1)\, T 
= \pi(n+1)(2r_1 + nT). 
$$
Recall that $r_2 = r_1 + nT$, so
$$
L = \pi(n+1)(r_1 + r_2)
$$
Let's multiply by $T$ and equate this formula with the original formula {\ref{length}) for the length of the roll:
$$
\pi(n+1)(r_1 + r_2)\, T = \pi\, {r_2}^2 - \pi\, {r_1}^2
$$
or
$$
(n+1) T = r_2 - r_1
$$
Finally,
\begin{align}
n = \frac{r_2 - r_1}{T} - 1. 
\end{align}
Converting back to diameters, and discarding the ${}-1$, as it's just an approximation of a large number anyway,
$$
n = \frac{d_2 - d_1}{2T}
$$

Comment: Sorry, i am really layman in math. How i'm gonna find how many turns is needed to get 180 m of sheet using your formula (using d1 = 0.5 and d2 = 2)?

Comment: So you want $n$ in terms of $L$, $d_1$, and $d_2$? That's a just a rearrangement of the formula in the middle of the calculation: $L = \pi(n+1)(r_1 + r_2)$.

Comment: Ignoring the ${}+1$, as this is an approximation anyway, 
$$
n \approx \frac{L}{\pi(r_1 + r_2)} = \frac{2L}{\pi(d_1 + d_2)}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. If you're content with it, you should mark the question as "answered" so it gets removed from the queue.